# Creating a function with one argument of class string that includes a comma

Tags: r, function, user-defined-functions, text-parsing

Is there any way of writing a function that takes only one argument of class string which includes commas and prints it? Something like follows:

```
function(i am dumb, very dumb)
>"i am dumb, very dumb"
```

I have tried in many different ways, however every time the comma appears R treats it as a separate argument. Is there any way of getting around this?

Thank you

Comment: What you may be looking for involves non-standard evaluation of arguments to a function. This topic is not trivial, but assuming your rationale is solid, one place to read up on it is [Hadley's Advanced R chapter on NSE](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html). The solution will likely involve `substitute`, perhaps `deparse`, and almost certainly `paste(..., sep = ", ")` to get what you want. Admittedly, not knowing the full picture, I seriously wonder if doing this is what you ultimately need.

Comment: To answer the straight-forward question, you can input strings with commas which will be treated the same as strings without commas. Here, you seem to be defining a function, so you'll want a variable name, say `dumbstring`. Then, when you call the function, you'll input the string with quotations, i.e.  `functionname(dumbstring = "i am dumb, very dumb")`. If you need variable names with commas you would need to follow @r2evans advice.